# How to get past this warning -> RemovedInDjango110Warning: Operator '=' is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Use '==' instead

Tags: python, django

I was trying to create a user instance in Django.

```
newuser = User.objects.create(username = username, email = email)
```

and got this warning and stuck here with a user created in the database.

> project/new_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py:168: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Operator '=' is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Use '==' instead.

I am using Django 1.9.5 and python3.6.6.

Comment: are you sure this is the line which is giving this error?

Comment: yes, I am getting this error just after the creation of user Instance.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is not caused by your `User.objects.create()` call. It is coming from one of your templates where you are using `=` instead of `==` in an `if` tag.

To stop the warning, you would change

```
{% if foo = 'bar' %}
```

to

```
{% if foo == 'bar' %}
```

If you can't tell where the warning is coming from, you can filter the warnings to raise an exception, then you'll get the full traceback.

```
import warnings
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango110Warning
warnings.simplefilter('error', DeprecationWarning)

# Now run code that raises the warning and you'll get a full error traceback
```

Comment: I just try to create a user instance by debugging the code using the debugger. it throws the same warning. so not sure but on the creation of the user instance, I am getting this warning.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the line `User.objects.create()` you have shown. Unless you can show specifically where the warning is coming from we can't help any more.

Comment: @pradhumntrivedi
See the features removed in django 1.10, it is clearly stated - "Support for the = comparison operator in the if template tag is removed." (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10), you must be missing something.

Comment: I can not find any solution regarding this @VaibhavGupta As I implemented this through a python script with no relation to any template but I still stuck with this warning.

Comment: I've already showed how you can use `warnings` to see where the error is coming from. If you can't get that to work, you could install Django 1.10. The invalid code (e.g. `{% if foo = 'bar' %}`) will then generate an error instead of a warning. Note that Django 1.9 is end of life, you should upgrade to the latest Django 1.11 LTS or Django 2.1.